# VirtualBox - Is it possible to connect to prioritise network cable over wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox

We are working on a very old Windows machine that is connected to a secure private LAN network cable (sadly, it is not accessible through other common conventional methods) and we are unable to get access any other way except through the machine.

A colleague has suggested using VirtualBox, he suggests to make the VirtualBox listen to the network cable AND use our wifi but have a priority between the two, or at the very least have the ability to work on both networks.

Sadly, I know very little about VirtualBox, NAT or networks, according to some light reading I think he means bridging but I am not sure.

ie,

> With bridged networking, VirtualBox uses a device driver on your host
>   system that filters data from your physical network adapter. This
>   driver is therefore called a "net filter" driver. This allows
>   VirtualBox to intercept data from the physical network and inject data
>   into it, effectively creating a new network interface in software.
>   From: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

I am wondering if someone can help; is it possible to  prioritise network cable over wifi, or make it so that we can connect both the WIFI and network cable to VirtualBox?

Thanks

Comment: We will be connecting both WIFI and the network cable to the VirtualBox

Comment: "LAN network cable (sadly, it is not accessible through other common conventional methods)" That is a VERY conventional method.